# RoutingMissingException using NEST IndexMany<>

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've been working on converting my ElasticSearch (ES) 0.9 code to work with ES 1.0. This has required an upgrade of NEST to the latest pre-release version.

I've been trying to bulk index a set of child documents. I've set up their mapping as:

```
"stocks": {           
            "_parent": {
                "type": "products"
            },
            "_timestamp": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "stock": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
```

This was created in ES 0.9. When I've put this into ES 1.0, it automatically adds a Routing property with 'Required' set to 'true'. A search on Google suggests that this was always required to enable a parent-child document setup but the property never explicitly appeared when I examined the documents in my 0.9 shard.

"Ok..." I think to myself. Next, I have the following code block for NEST:

```
 var bulkParams = postQueue.Select(p => new BulkParameters<Stock>(p) { Parent = p.id.ToString()});
 IElasticsearchResponse c = ec.IndexMany(bulkParams, null, "stocks").ConnectionStatus;
```

This returns a NullReferenceException. After some guesswork I added the Id parameter into the BulkParameters:

```
 var bulkParams = postQueue.Select(p => new BulkParameters<Stock>(p) { Id = p.id.ToString(), Parent = p.id.ToString()});
```

Which seems to work, but the request returns a error response from ES:

400 Bad Request with JSON error message:

***error=RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [test_index]/[stocks]/[xx]]***

(where xx is the id of the document)

I'm assuming I have to insert a Routing string somewhere, but I do not know where. I've tried adding a 'Routing' parameter into the BulkParameters but that did not work at all. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for `IndexMany()` with wrapped `BulkParameters` has been removed in `NEST 1.0.0 beta 1`

If you want to use a bulk with more advanced parameters you now have to use the `Bulk()` command.

The beta sadly still shipped with the `BulkParameters` class [in the assembly](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.0.0-beta1/src/Nest/Domain/Parameters/BulkParameters.cs)

This has since been removed in the develop branch and will be released in the next beta update.

So what happens now is that you are actually indexing ``` "bulkparameters``1``" ``` type documents and not `"stock"` with proper individual bulk metadata set.

See [here for an example](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Core/Bulk/BulkTests.cs#L134-L138) on how to use `Bulk()` to index many objects at once while configuring advanced parameters for individual items.

Comment: Link to example is a 404